# Which forecast method with only twenty datapoints (yearly)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, time-series, regression

i am faced with the challenge of forecasting a specific market. For this purpose, I have market figures for the last 20 years. However, these are really only available on an annual basis. there is therefore no possibility of obtaining the data on a quarterly or monthly basis. are there any suggestions for this?

the goal should be to forecast the next 2-3 years resulting from it

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong with assuming the following in your case:

1. There is only 20 years of data on annual basis without seasonality details,
2. Forecasting is to be made on annual basis for the next 2-3 years,
3. No more data is either available or can be found,

Then, you may try one of the techniques mentioned here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/CBREG/ch06s02s02s01.html

The accuracy and performance of the model may not be significant due to the constraints.